# node-telegram-bot-api: How to register next step handler in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x

I have the code wroten in Python, but I wanted to write it in JS on node-telegram-bot-api, in python I used PyTelegramBotAPI. So in Python PyTelegramBotAPI has a function which is a `bot.register_next_step_handler()`, but I don't see it in JS. Is there any way to re-create this function or did this function is? Anyway, sorry for bad english...

I tried to search in the web, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

I have this code wroten in Python

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(<TOKEN>)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
if message.text == "⚙️Zminyty abetku bota⚙️":
            markup2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
            markup2.add(telebot.types.KeyboardButton("Кирилиця"))
            markup2.add(telebot.types.KeyboardButton("Latynycja"))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Vyberit' latynku", reply_markup=markup2)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, changeabet)

def changeabet(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users""")
    list = cur.fetchall()
    use_lat = False
    for el in list:
        if el[0] == message.from_user.id:
            if el[1] == 1:
                use_lat = True

    if message.text == "Latynycja":
        cur.execute("""UPDATE users SET use_lat = ? WHERE user_tel_id = ?""", (1, message.from_user.id))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Uspišno!", reply_markup=menu_markup_lat)
    elif message.text == "Кирилиця":
        cur.execute("""UPDATE users SET use_lat = ? WHERE user_tel_id = ?""", (0, message.from_user.id))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Успішно!", reply_markup=menu_markup)
    else:
        if not use_lat:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Будь ласка, зробіть вибір.")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Bud' laska, zrobit' vybir.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, changeabet)
```

and I want to write it in JS because I need it, but I don't see in JS on node-telegram-bot-api alternatives for Python `bot.register_next_step_handler` in PyTelegramBotAPI